# Call script function (written in .gs file in Google drive) from Google sheets button

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want different users to be able to edit my Google sheet and my scripts.

Based on the answer [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/127393/how-can-i-prevent-editors-from-accessing-the-script-editor-in-google-sheets) I made a script file in Google drive and used it to successfully manipulate data in the Google sheet.

However, I want users to be able to call the script function from within the Google sheet by clicking a button. When I assign the script function name to a button in my sheet, I get "Script function testFunction could not be found" error.

### Update

I have attached following script to my button:

```
function runTest(){
  TestScript.testFunction()
}
```

TestScript is the name of the standalone script project. However, I get "Reference error: TestScript not defined" when I press the button.

Comment: If you want to run a script from another project you’ll have to use Google app script advanced API

Comment: To use the script as a library is included in your direction? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use functions from scripts that are not bounded to your Spreadsheet in your Spreadsheet script you should use [libraries](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries).

To do so, follow these steps:

1. In your script that will run the function (i.e the script that is an outsider for your Spreadsheet as it is not bounded) go to the menu bar and select **File -> Manage versions** and create a new version with the title you want.
2. Then, in the same script head over to **File -> Project Properties** and copy the `Script ID`.
3. Go to your Spreadsheet's bounded script (this is the script that has the function that will be triggered by your button) and in the menu bar head over to **Resources -> Libraries**, insert the `Script ID`, select the latest version and give the library a name to be used locally (for example if it is set to `Test` you will call its functions using `Test.myFunction();`.
4. Remember to assign your bounded script function to the button in the Sheet.

Comment: The solution almost worked perfectly. Now I get the error "You do not have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.openById. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets" I have searched a bit and apprently I need to link the bound script to a custom menu? The unbound / standalone script works but when I call it from the bound script it needs permissions?

Comment: So when I run the function from a button I had to accept the usual permissions and I did not get any errors. What is the code in your separate script that is asking for these permissions? In my environment it worked fine with a button and I did not have to use a custom menu. How are you creating and linking this button to your script?

Comment: The line which causes problems is `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("....");`

Comment: And how did you link your button to your Spreadsheet's script? In my case I did the following: in the menu bar I have selected **Insert -> Drawing**, rectangle shape and once it has been added I have linked it by selecting **Assign script** and then adding my bounded script function name (in my case ```myFunction```). I have also tested with ```SpreadsheetApp.openById()``` and it worked fine for me too.

Comment: Also have you splicitely set any scopes in any of your scripts? Are you using any triggers?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I figured out the problem. My user was not the owner of the spreadsheet file. I made a new spreadsheet file and the code worked perfectly.

Comment: If you know a way to call standalone script from sheet for which user is editor not owner, please share.

Comment: Yes, you must grant a read level access at least to your library script to all the users that will be using this library and give them the project key. For more information check [this piece of documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries#sharing_a_library) that details how to share a library to other users.